# How to get all database having upper case character after some word using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list all database which has the common starting word and after it should have uppercase letters. (using MYSQL)

```
eg: 
    test_vino_JY
    test_vino_JI
    test_vino_ij
    test_vino_klm
```

In the above example i want to list only test_vino_JY, test_vino_JI

May i know how to do that. I tried using the below query, its not working. Please help me on this.

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` REGEXP '^test_vino_+[A-Z]';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show` doesn't accept regexes, it only accepts a `show foo like '%...%'` wildcard-type matches. You'll have to select against the `information_schema` pseudo-db:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME REGEXP '...';
```

Comment: is my regexp is correct? thats not working for me. :(

Comment: regexes aren't case sensitive, unless you do `where ... regexp binary '...'`